# JPA - How to add child entities to aggregate roots

Tags: java, jpa, domain-driven-design

It's the first time I apply DDD. I use EclipseLink. I've the following issue.
My root entity has a child entity (`child`). This child entity has also a child entity (`childSpecs`).

I want to make the root entity (`root`) responsible for creating and adding child entities:

```
root.addChild(arg1, agr2);
```

But `child` can't exist without `childSpecs`. I made `child` responsible for creating `childSpecs`.

So when calling `addChild(arg1, arg2)` the objects `child` and `childSpecs` are created and are related to eachother and `root`. But `childSpecs` has a mandatory field which keeps the id of `child`. But when `child` is created it hasn't yet an id. That will be created when it gets persisted. (Currently I use the JPA functionality TableGenerator to generate my surrogate key values.)
Does someone know a solutions to solve this.
My thought was to build my own id-generator. But that might be a little bit complicated when taking in acount concurrency.

**Additional info:**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "root")
public class Root implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "root_id")
    private Integer        rootId;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "root")
    private List<RootChild>   rootChildList;
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "root_child")
public class RootChild implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "root_child_id")
    private Integer           rootChildId;

    @JoinColumn (name = "root_id", referencedColumnName = "root_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Root               root;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "rootChild")
    private List<RootChildSpecs> rootChildSpecsList;
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "root_child_specs")
public class RootChildSpecs implements Serializable, Mutable<RootChildSpecs> {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected RootChildSpecsPK rootChildSpecsPK;

    @JoinColumn (
        name                 = "root_child_id",
        referencedColumnName = "root_child_id",
        insertable           = false,
        updatable            = false
        )

     @ManyToOne (optional = false)
     private RootChild          rootChild;
```

-

```
@Embeddable
public class RootChildSpecsPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "root_child_id")
    private int rootChildId;

    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "d_rec")
    private int dRec;

    @Basic (optional = false)
    @Column (name = "t_rec")
    private int tRec;
```

Comment: can you post details about your mapping (i.e. ids + relevant relationships) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.0 allows deriving IDs from references, allowing you to mark the RootChildSpecs->RootChild as being part of rootChildSpecs' ID and pulling the value from it when it gets generated.  A simple example is here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers

You can mark the relationship using @mapsId to point to the attribute it mapps in the embeddedid since Embeddedid and pk classes cannot contain relationships themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Though, I couldn't get it working. For experimental purposes I replaced the composite primary key with a surrogate primary key. That does work like a charm. This could be a reason to stop using composite primary keys altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using an EmbeddedId and instead put the @Id on your @ManyToOne to RootChild and use an @IdClass.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0

Comment: I looked up this [page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/IdClass) and tried, but couldn't get it working. I decided to replace the composite primairy key with a surrogate primairy key.